# Increasing partition size ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, partitioning, wine, disk-usage, microsoft-office

I am new to Ubuntu and really appreciate your patience with my questions.

I have been trying to download horrid MS Office due to certain needs because of the nature of my work. I have been trying to downloads MS Office 2007/2010 through WINE. However, I keep facing the problem of having insufficient disk space. Find attached an image of the same How do I increase the size of /dev/sda7? or alternatively how do I "use a wineprefix that is located on the other partition" to use the other partition? I use Ubuntu 11.04.

IT IS REALLY URGENT that I sort out the issue, and would be forever grateful!

I can't seem to attach an image, as I am a new user, so here are the details

```
Device        Directory            Type   Total      Free       Available    Used
/dev/sda7     /                    ext4   5.5GiB     303.3Mib   14.7MiB      5.3GiB 99%

/dev/sda6    /media/cd025f16-      ext 4  556.8GiB   460.2GiB   431.9GiB     96.7GiB 18% 
             433b-4a90-abb6-bb7
             a025d0450   

/dev/sda2    /media/SYSTEM         fuseblk 100MiB    75.9MiB    75.9MiB     24.1MiB   24%
RESERVED
```

Comment: ok the details seem to have gone haywire!

Comment: Basically, in the file system, 
I have got a device /dev/sda7 details of which are directory /, type ext 4, total 5.5GiB, free 303.3Mib,  available 14.7MiB, Used 99% (5.3GiB). This is what I want to increase the size of. Then there is /dev/sda6 details of which are directory /dev/sda6 /media/cd025f16-433b-4a90-abb6-bb7 a025d0450, type ext4, total 556.8GiB, Free 460.2GiB, available 431.9 GiB, used 18% (96.7GiB). So there is basically all this free space I want to make use of.

Comment: There is one last device /dev/sda2, details of which are directory /dev/sda2 /media/SYSTEM RESERVED, type fuseblk, total 100MiB, free 75.9MiB , available 75.9MiB, used 24.1 MiB (24%).... I wish I could have just pasted an image, but I am not allowed as a new user! sorry about that

Comment: I have rolled back your edit to recover filesystem details.

Answer (score 1):

Boot with a livecd.

You need to shrink sda7 and then increase the size of sda6.

Backup before you start. It is not likely that anything will go wrong - but if it does you will be glad.

Do not stop gparted once it starts - it could take time to do.

Open gparted - right click on sda7 and Resize

[image]

Select the left hand edge of sda7 - arrow not hand - and shrink to the right.

Once shrink you will have unallocated space between the partitions

[image]

You can then right click sda6, resize again.

Select the right hand edge and resize to the right to fill the space.

This might change the UUID of the partition and cause grub to fail, I would while in the livecd reinstall grub to ensure you can boot.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstall_from_the_LiveCD

In a terminal - assuming that sda7 is still called that.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt

sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```